# Can I configure Ubuntu Server to use a laptop battery as UPS?

Tags: server, power-management, laptop, battery

Before I purchase a laptop for testing, I'm trying to figure out if Ubuntu Server can support or if there is a package to support using a laptop as a server with the laptop battery functioning as I'm normally used to with UPS, where the server will shut itself down automatically per the configured tool.

Comment: Not a full answer, but you could likely write something in bash to do what you're looking for. Basically, something that detects when the battery is no longer being charged and then shut down after a set time. I would caution you, though, as this may degrade the battery.

Comment: @RocketSEA After posting the question I was just thinking that somehow Desktop detects laptop batteries without issue, at least in my experience, so if I could figure out how that is accomplished, then implement on Server (or maybe it already is?).

Comment: Look at `apcupsd*`.